# .Net Standard 2.0 Class Library produces error CS0246

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

So I am working on a Asp.Net Core 2.0 web application. I am doing some refactoring and wanted to move some classes into a referenced class library. I did some reading and found that .Net Standard is the new way to go about that.

So I created a new .Net Standard 2.0 Class library then created my class. I was able to compile the code just fine. I referenced the library in my Asp.Net Core 2.0 web app and everything was fine until I tried to use the class. It's just a simple model class no logic just properties.

When I try to use it I get  error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'LoginRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `LoginRequest` your class declared in the library? Do you actually have `using` directive for namespace where it's defined?

Comment: Add your *.csproj file of your web application, the *.csproj for the library, the `LoginRequest` class, and the code referencing the `LoginRequest`. The reference isn't getting passed down, and the problem exists somewhere between those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through the same flaw. If you are adding a new file in .NET Standard library then you need to restart the Visual Studio to make that file's code come into effect. However, your intelisense will work without any VS restart.

Alternatively, you can add your class to an already existing file.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Hopefully they get that fix and the intellisense working soon.